# How to resolve XDMP-CONFLICTINGUPDATES?

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-dhf

This Question is in reference with Data Hub Framework-

I am having 3-4 conditions in which i am doing operations like `xdmp:node-replace` and `xdmp:document-delete` and after all the conditions i am trying to insert the document using `xdmp:document-insert`.

When i am running the conditions independently by commenting the other conditions then it is working fine but if i am trying to run 2 or more conditions together- i am getting **XDMP-CONFLICTINGUPDATES**

```
$envelope is coming from STAGING Database which i am using in writer.xqy
```

The code sample is as below-

```
let $con1 := if($envelope/*:test/text() eq "abc")
                 then xdmp:node-replace(....) else ()
let $con2 := if($envelope/*:test/text() eq "123")
                 then xdmp:node-replace(....) else ()
let $con1 := if($envelope/*:test/text() eq "cde")
                 then xdmp:document-delete(....) else ()
return if($envelope//*FLAG/text() eq "1")
    then
   xdmp:document-insert($id, $envelope, xdmp:default-permissions(), map:get($options, "entity"))
```

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 4):

`XDMP-ConflictingUpdates` means you are trying to update the same node more than once within a single transaction. Solving these types of errors can be infamously tricky and are a rite of passage for every MarkLogician.

In your case, this is caused by updating a node with `xdmp:node-replace` and then updating the document node which is the parent of that node with `xdmp:document-insert`. Thus, because you are updating both the node and its parent, you are in effect updating that node twice causing the error. Or, this may also occur from trying to both delete and insert a document at the same URI within the same transaction.

Here is a simple query you can run in QConsole to reproduce this behavior:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

xdmp:document-insert("/test.xml", <test><value></value></test>);

xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $d := fn:doc("/test.xml")

let $_ := xdmp:node-replace($d//value, <value>test</value>)

return
  xdmp:document-insert("/test.xml", $d)
```

In the case of this demonstration, as well as your code, the `xdmp:document-insert` is redundant and can simply be removed.

Comment: Rob- In my case i can't remove the xdmp:document-insert at last because at the end of operation i have to insert my document to the final database. Any Suggestion how should i do that ?

Comment: @Shalini Nothing in the code you shared suggests you are placing it into a different database than the database you perform the xdmp:node-replace operation in. If you're planning to eval the document-insert operation into a different database then I recommend running all the code you shared in that database so that you can remove the xdmp:document-insert and don't need to deal with in-memory operations or other heavy code modifications.

Comment: Rob- I am not placing it in different database. This is part of Data Hub Framework and the entire code i have written as part of my WRITER plugin. As you know The writer plugin has to ingest the data at last using xdmp:document-insert. So i have to use xdmp:document-insert anyhow.

Comment: @Shalini You should be able to modify the writer plugin to finish any way you want to. You shouldn't have to finish with an xdmp:document-insert. xdmp:document-insert returns an empty sequence. So anything yielding an empty sequence at the end will do just fine.

Comment: Rob- Will try to do that. The problem i am facing is the xdmp:node-replace of condition 1 is giving conflict with either xdmp:document-delete or xdmp:document-insert of other conditions.

Comment: @Shalini Right. Unless you are running other document operations not shown here within your transaction you should be able to limit it down to 1 by simply returning an empty sequence instead of xdmp:docoument-insert at the end.

Comment: Thank you Rob i tried the same approach and it helped :)

Answer (score 4):

Likely the XQuery statement above is attempting multiple updates to the same node in the same single-statement transaction. The `xdmp:node-replace` calls are performing updates at each operation to the same node. See the [documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions#id_46915) for more details.

Here are two solutions that may work for you

1. Use conditional statements to decide what kind of update needs to be performed on the node, e.g., whether the node need to be deleted, whether the node needs to be updated and how. At the end of your script you could then apply the update behavior to the node.
2. Perform in-memory updates to the node then commit the node to the database at the end of the transaction. Here is one library you could use https://github.com/ryanjdew/XQuery-XML-Memory-Operations

Comment: Don't ever solve a transactional problem by running more transactions. In the event one fails you'll be left with data that was broken in transit and you'll have to write new to code to repair it. Not to mention that you will quickly kill your performance doing this. If your code is so messy you're tempted to run multiple transactions you'd be better off doing in-memory updates with a single document insert at the end. Your recommended solution appears to be what the asker is doing now, except for the unnecessary document-insert at the end.

Comment: Fair point, I'll remove that recommendation. The asker is performing multiple updates to the same node with xdmp:node-replace. This doesn't follow a behavior pattern implementation necessary to perform the correct update behavior at the end of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

One general possibility for complicated updates:  use XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

This is multi transaction statement. There are multiple ways to handle it in your scenario:

1. Use xdmp:eval
2. Use mem library of MarkLogic to replace your nodes
3. Rewrite your Query to avoid transaction conflict